# In my code getArgument is returning null every time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried each and every type of solution but the fragment get argument method is returning null always.

This is my fragment code.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);
       
        **String data1 = getArguments().getString("data");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getArgument1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**
}
```

In the above code data1 always return null.
This is my main activity code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     
        chipNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavBar);
        chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container1, new mainActivityFragment()).commit();

        chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.home:

                        **fragment = new mainActivityFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("data","anything");
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);**

                        break;
                    case R.id.menu:
                        fragment = new menuFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.corona:
                        fragment = new CoronaFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container1, fragment).commit();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is `data1 ` and `getArgument1 ` the same thing?

Comment: Has `chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener` been called?

Comment: yes data1 and getArgument1 both are same and yes chipNavigationBar is been called.

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned that there are 2 places you load the `mainActivityFragment()` - the first is by default, when there are no bundle args, and the second time when the `chipNavigationBar. setOnItemSelectedListener`  is called. Maybe try something like this:

```
static mainActivityFragment createMainActivityFragment() {
    mainActivityFragment fragment = new mainActivityFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data","anything");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

//IN ONCREATE:
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container1, mainActivityFragment.createMainActivityFragment()).commit();

//IN THE SWITCH
    case R.id.home:
        fragment = mainActivityFragment.createMainActivityFragment()
    break;
```

Then both instances should have the bundle

Comment: Sorry if my java has mistakes I'm so used to Kotlin

Comment: no worries, if it does work could you mark it as the answer?